# Best way to save Raw SQL queries in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

What is the best way to make raw SQL queries in django?
I have to search a table for the mode of another table. I could not find a way to solve this in django's ORM so I turned to raw SQL queries.
Yet creating all these very long queries in python is very unreadable and does not feel like a proper way to do this. Is there a way to save these queries in a neat format perhaps in the database.

I have to join three separate tables and compute the mode of a few columns on the last table. The length of the queries is getting very big and the code to make these queries becomes very unreadable. An example query would be

```
SELECT * FROM "core_assembly" INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "core_taxonomy" INNER JOIN(SELECT "core_phenotypic"."taxonomy_id"  , \
array_agg("core_phenotypic"."isolation_host_NCBI_tax_id") FILTER (WHERE "core_phenotypic"."isolation_host_NCBI_tax_id" IS NOT NULL) \
AS super_set_isolation_host_NCBI_tax_ids FROM core_phenotypic GROUP BY "core_phenotypic"."taxonomy_id") "mode_table" ON \
"core_taxonomy"."id"="mode_table"."taxonomy_id") "tax_mode" ON "core_assembly"."taxonomy_id"="tax_mode"."id" WHERE  ( 404=ANY(super_set_isolation_host_NCBI_tax_ids));
```

Where I would have a very big parse function to make all the WHERE clauses based on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()

raw_query = "write your query here"
cursor.execute(raw_query)
```

You can also run raw queries for models. eg. `MyModel.objects.raw('my query')`.

Read [Performing raw SQL queries | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did not know about the connection method. Yet this still is not a way to solve the creation of queries in a neat readable way. I have to join three separate tables, so the query is getting enormously big and unreadable.